# diff-friendly XML modifying tool

Tags: python, xml, git, diff

I have lots of .xml files in my git repo. When edit them by hand, I'd rather keep the changes diff-friendly.

For example:

before:

```xml
<Item         shape="circle" color='red' location="left">
    <stuff     /><!-- some comment-->
  <thing/>
</Item>
```

after:

```xml
<Item         shape="circle" color='red'>
    <stuff     /><!-- some comment-->
</Item>
```

diff: (The bold part renders red in the shell)

> `$ git diff HEAD^..HEAD --color-words=.`
>   `diff --git a/x.xml b/x.xml`
>   `index 97855cd..baefd5f 100644`
>   `--- a/x.xml`
>   `+++ b/x.xml`
>   `@@ -1,4 +1,3 @@`
>   `<Item         shape="circle" color='red'`**`location="left"`**`>`
>   `<stuff     /><!-- some comment-->`
>   **`<thing/>^M`**
>   `</Item>`

However, when there are lots of files to modify,
I want to have some tools (preferably in Python) to do it automatically.
For example, use XPATH to delete all the `location` attributes
of `Item` tags with attribute `color='red'`, yet be diff-friendly.

If there's a XML parser that can provide you the original location of each element in the original bytes stream, with a little bit of programming I think it can be done. But I didn't find any such parser.

Do you have some good ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Visual Studio Code, you could search in Extensions for XPath Notebook which might help with reading the files.